# How to deserialize a dictionary using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, .net, json, deserialization

I have the following model:

```
[DataContract]
public class MessageHeader
{
    private Guid? messageId;

    public Guid MessageId
    {
        get
        {
            if (messageId == null)
                messageId = Guid.NewGuid();

            return messageId.Value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Parameters { get; set; } // Can't deserialize this

    [DataMember]
    public Action Action { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public User InitiatingUser { get; set; }
}
```

Now for some unknown reason, [DataContractJsonSerializer can't deserialize JSON into a dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) (See additional details section).
Unfortunately DataContractJsonSerializer is also sealed for reasons that are beyond me.
I need a way to get around it, does anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there isn't a dictionary type in javascript it's rather difficult to have JSON deparse into one. What you're going to have to do is write a converter yourself.

However, that's also true on most custom serialization objects, so hopefully that comes as no big surprise.

Now it should, however, read in as a KeyValuePair so you can try that, to see if it's at least deserializing for you. Rather, you would need a `List<KeyValuePair<>>`

What a `Dictionary<string,string>` translates into for JSON:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>; 
dict["Red"] = "Rosso"; 
dict["Blue"] = "Blu"; 
dict["Green"] = "Verde";

[{"Key":"Red","Value":"Rosso"},
 {"Key":"Blue","Value":"Blu"},
 {"Key":"Green","Value":"Verde"}]
```

The same associative from javascript into JSON:

```
var a = {}; 
a["Red"] = "Rosso"; 
a["Blue"] = "Blu"; 
a["Green"] = "Verde";

{"Red":"Rosso","Blue":"Blu","Green":"Verde"}
```

So there's the problem in a nutshell.

---

A few followup links for usefulness

http://my6solutions.com/post/2009/06/17/The-serialization-and-deserialization-of-the-generic-Dictionary-via-the-DataContractJsonSerializer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.collectiondatacontractattribute.aspx

Comment: Why can't DataContractJsonSerializer serialize the dictionary as: Dictionary["ObjectName"] = Value;

Comment: Also, CollectionDataContractAttribute doesn't apply to DataContractJsonSerializer, again for absolutely no reason. About the first link, what do I do if I don't have JavaScriptSerializer since it's a Web DLL.

Comment: since it's a `Web` dll? I don't understand? You can use any library in the .NET GAC just by referencing it. That's the power of the .NET library. Just because it's in System.Web or whatever, that doesn't mean anything. It's just a namespace for logical organization of objects, methods and the like. And as for _Why can't DCJS serialize the dictionary that way_, idk, but I've shown you the problem above.

Comment: I've investigated a bit more and it seems that JSON.NET does exactly what I need regarding the dictionary, that actually shows how much this implementation of the serialization is bad. Thanks.

Comment: @drachenstern: The problem with the first link's approach is that it doesn't deserialize a dictionary that is inside my object.

Comment: @the_drow ~ oh good point I hadn't thought of that, I was thinking if you inlineparsed it...

Comment: @drachenstern: That's why DataContractJsonSerializer is really bad, it's a basic feature and the most annoying thing is that the class is SEALED!